# Simulating a series from ARMA (2,2) in R (RStudio)

Tags: r, time-series, modeling, montecarlo

I have an ARMA(2,2) process with parameters phi1 = 1.3; phi2 = -0.58; theta1 = -1.32; theta2 = 0.63 and would like to simulate a number of series with these estimates.

I am aware that I could code something along the lines of:

yt<- c + phi1*y[j-1] +phi2 *y[j-2] + ...

However, I would like to know if there a means of simulating my series with my parameters in a more formal way, e.g using a single function such as **arma()** or **ts()**?

Comment: Lookup `arima.sim()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop to simulate the ARMA model on your own

```
phi1 = 1.3
phi2 = -0.58
theta1 = -1.32
theta2 = 0.63 

n = 100
y = numeric(n)
y[1] = y[2] = 0
eps = rnorm(n)

for(i in 3:n)
{
y[i] = phi1*y[i-1] + phi2*y[i-2] + theta1*eps[i-1] + theta2*eps[i-2] + eps[i]
}
```

You can include this in a function to repeate your simulations easier

```
arma = function(n,phi1,phi2,theta1,theta2)
{
n = 100
y = numeric(n)
y[1] = y[2] = 0
eps = rnorm(n)

for(i in 3:n)
{
y[i] = phi1*y[i-1] + phi2*y[i-2] + theta1*eps[i-1] + theta2*eps[i-2] + eps[i]
}

return(y)
}
```

with

```
arma(100,1.3,-0.58,-1.32,0.63)
```

or you can use the implemented function `arima.sim()` as mentioned before

```
library(stats)
arima.sim(100, model=list(ar=c(1.3,-0.58), ma=c(-1.32,0.63)))
```

maybe you should add a burn-in period in the function to simulate it on your own to eliminate the initial effect from the first 0's in `y`